# Adding 2 Int Lists Together F#

Tags: matrix, vector, f#

I am working on homework and the problem is where we get 2 int lists of the same size, and then add the numbers together. Example as follows.

```
    vecadd [1;2;3] [4;5;6];; would return [5;7;9]
```

I am new to this and I need to keep my code pretty simple so I can learn from it. I have this so far. (Not working)

```
    let rec vecadd L K =
         if L <> [] then vecadd ((L.Head+K.Head)::L) K else [];;
```

I essentially want to just replace the first list (L) with the added numbers. Also I have tried to code it a different way using the match cases.

```
    let rec vecadd L K =
       match L with
         |[]->[]
         |h::[]-> L
         |h::t -> vecadd ((h+K.Head)::[]) K
```

Neither of them are working and I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: _Why_ don't you want to return a new list?

Comment: Using [Seq.zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.zip%5B't1,'t2%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) and returning a new collection seems the most idiomatic approach to me

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The assignment didn't specify if I should or shouldn't return a new list. Usually I go the safe way and don't but in this case I guess it wouldn't matter. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: "Safe way" and "modify the existing list" are incompatible ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First**, your idea about modifying the first list instead of returning a new one is misguided. Mutation (i.e. modifying data in place) is the number one reason for bugs today (used to be `goto`, but that's been banned for a long time now). Making every operation produce a new datum rather than modify existing ones is much, much safer. And in some cases it may be even more performant, quite counterintuitively (see below).

**Second**, the way you're trying to do it, you're not doing what you think you're doing. The double-colon doesn't mean "modify the first item". It means "attach an item in front". For example:

```
let a = [1; 2; 3]
let b = 4 :: a    // b = [4; 1; 2; 3]
let c = 5 :: b    // c = [5; 4; 1; 2; 3]
```

That's how lists are actually built: you start with a empty list and prepend items to it. The `[1; 2; 3]` syntax you're using is just a syntactic sugar for that. That is, `[1; 2; 3] === 1::2::3::[]`.

So how do I modify a list, you ask? The answer is, you don't! F# lists are immutable data structures. Once you've created a list, you can't modify it.

This immutability allows for an interesting optimization. Take another look at the example I posted above, the one with three lists `a`, `b`, and `c`. How many cells of memory do you think these three lists occupy? The first list has 3 items, second - 4, and third - 5, so the total amount of memory taken must be 12, right? Wrong! The total amount of memory taken up by these three lists is actually just 5 cells. This is because list `b` is not a block of memory of length 4, but rather just the number `4` paired with a pointer to the list `a`. The number `4` is called "head" of the list, and the pointer is called its "tail". Similarly, the list `c` consists of one number `5` (its "head") and a pointer to list `b`, which is its "tail".

If lists were not immutable, one couldn't organize them like this: what if somebody modifies my tail? Lists would have to be copied every time (google "defensive copy").

So the only way to do with lists is to return a new one. What you're trying to do can be described like this: if the input lists are empty, the result is an empty list; otherwise, the result is the sum of tails prepended with the sum of heads. You can write this down in F# almost verbatim:

```
let rec add a b =
    match a, b with
    | [], [] -> []   // sum of two empty lists is an empty list
    | a::atail, b::btail -> (a + b) :: (add atail btail)  // sum of non-empty lists is sum of their tails prepended with sum of their heads
```

Note that this program is *incomplete*: it doesn't specify what the result should be when one input is empty and the other is not. The compiler will generate a warning about this. I'll leave the solution as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This is not tail recursive right? It needs to keep all the `(a+b)`s in the memory (stack) before it can build the final list. If this is correct, then we cannot add lists which has 5m elements

Comment: Yes, this is correct, this example is not tail-recursive.

Answer (score 5):

You can map over both lists together with List.map2 (see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map2%5B't1,'t2,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D))
It goes over both lists pairwise and you can give it a function (the first parameter of List.map2) to apply to every pair of elements from the lists. And that generates the new list.

```
 let a = [1;2;3]
 let b = [4;5;6]

 let vecadd  = List.map2 (+)

 let result  = vecadd a b
 printfn "%A" result
```

And if you want't to do more work 'yourself' something like this?

```
let a = [1;2;3]
let b = [4;5;6]

let vecadd l1 l2 = 
    let rec step l1 l2 acc = 
        match l1, l2 with
            | [],  [] -> acc
            | [], _ | _, [] -> failwithf "one list is bigger than the other"
            | h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 -> step t1 t2 (List.append acc [(h1 + h2)])
    step l1 l2 []
let result  = vecadd a b
printfn "%A" result
```

The step function is a recursive function that takes two lists and an accumulator to carry the result.

- In the last match statement it does three things

  - Sum the head of both lists
  - Add the result to the accumulator
  - Recursively call itself with the new accumulator and the tails of the lists
- The first match returns the accumulator when the remaining lists are empty
- The second match returns an error when one of the lists is longer than the other. 
  The accumulator is returned as the result when the remaining lists are empty.

The call `step l1 l2 []` kicks it off with the two supplied lists and an empty accumulator.

Comment: Really useful and easy but I was looking for something more like a match statement or a recursive function. I need to stick with what we're learning in class.

Comment: You can supply a `map2` function yourself `let map2 f xs ys=let rec aux acc=function x::xs,y::ys->aux(f x y::acc)(xs,ys)|_->List.rev acc in aux[](xs,ys)`

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for crossing two lists (multiply items with same index together):

```ml
let items = [1I..50_000I]
let another = [1I..50_000I]

let rec cross a b = 
    let rec cross_internal = function
        | r, [], [] -> r
        | r, [], t -> r@t
        | r, t, [] -> r@t
        | r, head::t1, head2::t2 -> cross_internal(r@[head*head2], t1, t2)
    cross_internal([], a, b)

let result = cross items another
result |> printf "%A,"
```

Note: not really performant. There are list object creations at each step which is horrible. Ideally the inner function `cross_internal` must create a mutable list and keep updating it.

Note2: my ranges were larger initially and using `bigint` (hence the `I` suffix in `50_000`) but then reduced the sample code above to just 50,500 elements.