# Matrix Adding F#

Tags: list, vector, f#

I am working on a program that adds matrices. (The same size) I have the vector add (adding 2 lists together), but my matadd doesn't work. It keeps returning the second list. Any ideas?

```
    let rec vecadd a b =
       match a, b with
        | [], [] -> []
        | a::at, b::bt -> (a + b) :: (vecadd at bt)
    //vecadd [1;2;3] [4;5;6];; Would return [5;7;9]

   let rec matadd a b =
       match [[a;b];[a;b]] with
        |[[h::t] ; [h2::t2]]-> (vecadd h h2 ) :: (matadd t t2)

   //matadd [[1;2];[3;4];[5;6]];[[1;2];[3;4];[5;6]];; Would return [[2;4][6;8];[10;12]]
```

See earlier question [Adding 2 Int Lists Together F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41728398/1243762) related to `vecadd`.

Comment: I suggest that you read up on language basics. Would be way more efficient. Personally, I recommend https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/.

Comment: Out of curiosity is this homework or self-learning and is this leading up to doing neural networks? Asking because if you are headed to neural networks then you will want to take a look at [Math.NET Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/). The library if very useful and I used it for a neural network project however the documentation IMHO needs more examples with F#. Yes, I know I could do a PR and probably should; maybe next time I swing back around to working with it for a few days instead of just one off calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the concept of pattern matching all jumbled up in your head.

When you match `[ [a;b]; [a;b] ]` with `[ [h::t]; [h2::t2] ]`, it matches `[a;b]` with `[h::t]` and `[a;b]` with `[h2::t2]` respectively. This means that you always get `h = h2 = a` and `t = t2 = [b]`. So when you vecadd `h` and `h2`, you're essentially just doubling `a`. I'm not going to explain further, because it just doesn't make any sense. I hope you'll be able to see it by now.

To add two lists of lists, you can apply the exact same logic that I gave you for adding the vectors themselves: the sum of two empty lists is an empty list; otherwise, the sum is the sum of lists' tails prepended by the sum of their heads. Or to translate it into F#:

```
let rec matadd a b =
    match a, b with
    | [], [] -> []
    | a::atail, b::btail -> (vecadd a b) :: (matadd atail btail)
```

**Also:**
When I gave you the `vecadd` code in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729181/180286), I didn't mean that you should just take it as a finished solution. In fact, I even told you outright that it's *incomplete* (which, by the way, applies just as well to the `matadd` example above).

It's great to understand recursion while you're learning, but for actual production code you shouldn't use it a lot. Recursion is tricky and easy to get wrong. Instead, you should try to hide recursion in small, general, easily testable functions, and then build all other operations on top of them. For lists, F# already gives you a bunch of such functions. One of them, the one that combines two lists in one, is called `zip`. Or, if you want to apply a transforming function to the item pairs as you go, use `map2`.

For example:

```
let vecadd a b = List.map2 (+) a b
let matadd a b = List.map2 vecadd a b
```

Comment: I have tried completing both the vecadd and the matadd with both of these lines of code:

 `| _::_,[]-> []          | [],_::_-> []`  and the program still gives me the second list. I looked back at your post on my other question and it seems like that's the only thing that was missing (even though vecadd worked).

Comment: If you paste your expression `matadd [[1;2];[3;4];[5;6]];[[1;2];[3;4];[5;6]];;` into F# interactive, it just gives you the second list, because it's not one expression, but two expressions. See the semicolon between the two matrices? That semicolon works the same way as a line break. The `matadd` function ends up with one missing argument (which is ok), not invoked at all, and the result of the whole thing is the second list. If you remove the semicolon and actually invoke `matadd`, it will crash on you complaining of incomplete pattern match.

Comment: Wow, that was the problem the whole time. I have found out how to counter all of the incomplete pattern matches by doing what you said. You've been very helpful.