# F# sum two sequences by element

Tags: f#

I am looking for a way to sum two sequences by element in F#.

For example, if I have these two sequences:

```
let first = seq [ 183.24; 170.15;174.17]
let second = seq [25.524;24.069;24.5]
```

I want to get the following result:

```
third list = [208.764;194.219;198.67]
```

What would be the simplest or the best way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728398/adding-2-int-lists-together-f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `zip` function :

```
let third = Seq.zip first second |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> x + y)
```

It will create a new sequence with a tuple where the first element is from `first` and second form `second`, then you can map and apply the addition of both elements.

As pointed in the comments, `map2` is another option, we could say that `map2` is equivalent to `zip` followed by `map`.

Comment: `Seq.map2 (+) first second` is also an option.

Answer (score 5):

The easies way to do this - use [`Seq.map2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map2%5B't1,'t2,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

```
let first = seq  [ 183.24; 170.15;174.17]
let second = seq [25.524;24.069;24.5]
//seq [208.764; 194.219; 198.67]
let third = Seq.map2 (+) first second
```